# How To find attendance Mispunch in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `tbl_attendance` in SQL Server with data is in this format

```
card_no adate         time
-----------------------------------------
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 09:30:00
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 11:00:00
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 12:00:00
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 15:00:00
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 16:00:00
13      2016-08-02    2016-08-02 09:30:00
```

but when I execute my query, I want to get results in this format

```
card_no adate         time_in                time_in
----------------------------------------------------------------
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 09:30:00    2016-08-01 11:00:00
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 12:00:00    2016-08-01 15:00:00
13      2016-08-01    2016-08-01 16:00:00    null
13      2016-08-02    2016-08-02 09:30:00    null
```

Please help as soon as possible

Comment: Are you expecting several punches in and out in a day? Otherwise you could just select the min and max time grouped by date and card no, and for max, do a NULLIF if they equal.

Comment: So write some code in a scripting or programming language to do it.  This sort of manipulation is turning SQL into a complicated scripting language.  Where as it is trivial if done in php, python, C#, Delphi, even javascript.

Comment: yes because i want to caculate time in between every in / out punching

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
             ((Row_number()OVER(partition BY [adate] ORDER BY [time])-1)%2) + 1 AS seq_no, 
             ((Row_number()OVER(partition BY [adate] ORDER BY [time])-1)/2) + 1 rang_no 
         FROM   Yourtable) 
SELECT [card_no], 
       [adate], 
       time_in = Min(CASE WHEN seq_no = 1 THEN [time] END), 
       time_in = Min(CASE WHEN seq_no = 2 THEN [time] END) 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY [card_no], 
          [adate], 
          rang_no
```

### Demo

***Schema Setup***

```
IF Object_id('tempdb.dbo.#Table1') is not null
DROP TABLE #Table1

CREATE TABLE #Table1
    ([card_no] int, [adate] date, [time] datetime);
```

***Sample Data***

```
INSERT INTO #Table1
    ([card_no], [adate], [time])
VALUES
    (13, '2016-08-01 00:00:00', '2016-08-01 09:30:00'),
    (13, '2016-08-01 00:00:00', '2016-08-01 11:00:00'),
    (13, '2016-08-01 00:00:00', '2016-08-01 12:00:00'),
    (13, '2016-08-01 00:00:00', '2016-08-01 15:00:00'),
    (13, '2016-08-01 00:00:00', '2016-08-01 16:00:00'),
    (13, '2016-08-02 00:00:00', '2016-08-02 09:30:00');
```

***Query***

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT *, 
             ((Row_number()OVER(partition BY [adate] ORDER BY [time])-1)%2) + 1 AS seq_no, 
             ((Row_number()OVER(partition BY [adate] ORDER BY [time])-1)/2) + 1 rang_no 
         FROM   #Table1) 
SELECT [card_no], 
       [adate], 
       time_in = Min(CASE WHEN seq_no = 1 THEN [time] END), 
       time_in = Min(CASE WHEN seq_no = 2 THEN [time] END) 
FROM   cte 
GROUP  BY [card_no], 
          [adate], 
          rang_no
```

***Result:***

```
card_no adate       time_in                   time_in
------  ----------  -----------------------   -----------------------
13      2016-08-01  2016-08-01 09:30:00.000   2016-08-01 11:00:00.000
13      2016-08-01  2016-08-01 12:00:00.000   2016-08-01 15:00:00.000
13      2016-08-01  2016-08-01 16:00:00.000   NULL
13      2016-08-02  2016-08-02 09:30:00.000   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way with OUTER APPLY (is used to get next row with time > than in current row) and ROW_NUMBER (with %2 to get only odd rows):

```
SELECT  t.card_no,
        t.adate,
        t.[time],
        t.time_in
FROM (
    SELECT  y.*,
            p.[time] as time_in,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y.card_no, y.adate ORDER BY y.[time])%2 as seq
    FROM YourTable y
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE [time] > y.[time] and [adate] = y.adate
        ORDER BY [time] ASC
    ) p
) as t
WHERE t.seq = 1
ORDER BY [time]
```

Output:

```
card_no         adate       time                time_in             
13              2016-08-01  2016-08-01 09:30:00 2016-08-01 11:00:00 
13              2016-08-01  2016-08-01 12:00:00 2016-08-01 15:00:00 
13              2016-08-01  2016-08-01 16:00:00 NULL                
13              2016-08-02  2016-08-02 09:30:00 NULL
```